# Displaying text inline with the icon and text transition not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a website with html and css.I have a side navigationbar as shown here [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dT60cEpwFMmTxkUGKKt0?p=options)

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
 margin :0;
 border :0;
 background-color:#222;
 
}
* {
 box-sizing : border-box;
}
.main-header {
 position : absolute ;
 width : 100% ;
 height : 56px;
 background-color : #55d6aa;
 z-index:4;
 
}

.main-content {
 padding-top :46px;
 
}

.side-nav {
    position : absolute;
    width:80px ;
    
    height:100vh;
    z-index:3;
    padding-top:44px;
    
   
}





.side-nav ul {
 list-style :0;
 padding :0;
 margin:0;
}

.side-nav ul li {
 padding : 20px 10px;
 border-bottom :1px solid #333;
 transition: width 2s;
 
}



.side-nav ul li:hover #item
{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width:200px;
float:center;
 
} 
.side-nav ul li:hover #sidebarIcon
{
 float:fixed;
}
#item {
 transition-timing-function: linear;
 
 font-size:16px;
 
}








 
.side-nav ul li a {
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration : none;
 
}



.side-nav ul li a i {
 color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 100px)
{
 .side-nav {
 width :80px;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li {
 text-align: center;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li span:nth-child(2) {
 display:none;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li i {
 font-size:  26px;
  }
 
 .main-content {
 
 margin-left:85px;
 }
 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px)
{
 
 .side-nav {
 width :80px;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li {
 text-align: center;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li span:nth-child(2) {
 display:none;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li i {
 font-size:  26px;
 }
 
 .main-content {
 
 margin-left:85px;
 }
 
 
 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main-header">
<a href="#" class="nav-trigger"><span></span></a>
</div>

 <div class="side-nav">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-calendar" id="sidebarIcon"></i></span>
      <span class="sideMenuItem" id="item">Text 1</span>
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-2" id="sidebarIcon" ></i></span>
      <span class="sideMenuItem" id="item">Text 2</span>

    </a></li>
    
    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-2" id="sidebarIcon"></i></span>
      <span class="sideMenuItem" id="item">Text 3</span>

    </a></li>
    
    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-2" id="sidebarIcon"></i></span>
      <span class="sideMenuItem" id="item">Text 4</span>

    </a></li>
    

   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>

 <div class="main-content">
  <p>asjjasjlasj</p>
 </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

The problem with the code is that ,when i hover over the icons the text values are not displayed inline with the icon .Also i want to add a transition effect from left to right to the text while it is revealing on hovering the icon.Both the things are not working.Please suggest me how to go about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Things to change for displaying the text:

1. Tag p is block level element and need to change it to `display:inline-block` in `main-content` div
2. The CSS `.side-nav ul li:hover #item`  contains `float:center` where there is nothing as float center
3. I think you need to change the dom structure to align it properly
   I am sure about first two but not about this one and if you want to do it take more CSS, I mean it will create a lot of confusions and may look odd with this structure.

And for animation, you need to use opacity and visibility where display property cannot be animated but it may take up space which will be awkward too. So if you follow the above you will get it perfectly.

[This will help you with animation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/) and to change the DOM, try "Text 1" to bring it near p tag or you need to give more code to change it perfectly. Otherwise changing CSS won't help too much.

Comment: change dom structure to what ? and can you edit the plunker and show about the text animation,or direct me to suitable tutorial online.I couldnt find any related to text